# Kafka consumer group in weird state

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

My Kafka consumer group was running just fine. I stopped it and subscribed to additional topic. Since then sometimes it gives errror and doesn't consume messgaes:

> Timeout during group to initialize

In kafka consumer group command output it shows negative lag then 0 lag even if no active streams.

Comment: Hi Anne, you will need to provide more information if you want people to help. Can you include the error you're seeing in the logs and maybe the Kafka log lines around that point?  Can you provide details of the topology you're running? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use any tool for inspecting Kafka?
This one looks promising https://www.kafkatool.com/ and maybe gives you some information about the consumers.

[image]